# Employee Scheduling Constraints Issue

Tags: python, scheduling, pyomo

I am currently trying to develop an employee scheduling tool in order to reduce the daily workload. I am using pyomo for setting up the model but unfortunately stuck on one of the constraint setting.

Here is the simplified background:

1. 4 shifts are available for assignation - RDO (Regular Day Off), M (Morning), D (Day) and N (Night). All of them are 8-hrs shift
2. Every employee will get 1 RDO per week and constant RDO is preferred (say staff A better to have Monday as day off constantly but this can be violate)
3. Same working shift (M / D / N) is preferred for every staff week by week **(the constraint that I stuck on)**
   a. Example 1 (RDO at Monday): The shift of Tuesday to Sunday should be / have better to be the same
   b. Example 2 (RDO at Thursday): The shift of Mon to Wed should be same as the last working day of prior week, while the shift of Fri to Sun this week also need to be same but not limit to be which shift

Since the RDO day (Mon - Sun) is different among employees, the constraint of point 3 also require to be changed people by people conditionally (say if RDO == "Mon" then do A ; else if RDO == "Tue" then do B), I have no idea how can it be reflected on the constraint as IF / ELSE statement cant really work on solver.

Appreciate if you can give me some hints or direction. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The constraints you are trying to create could be moderately complicated, and are very dependent on how you set up the problem, how many time periods you look at in the model, etc. etc. and are probably beyond the scope of 1 answer.  Are you taking an LP course in school?  If so, you might want to bounce your framework off of your instructor for ideas.

That aside, you might want to tackle the ROD by assigning each person a cost table based on their preferences and then putting in a small penalty in the objective based on their "costs" to influence the solver to give them their "pick" -- assumes the "picks" are relatively well distributed and not everybody wants Friday off, etc.

You could probably do the same with the shifts, essentially making a parameter that is indexed by [employee, shift] with "costs" and using that in the obj in a creative way.  This would be the easiest solution...  others get into counting variables, big-M, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could in this case use a switch case. Use the ROD as input and the cases are the days of the week. In the cases you can than to the rest of the planing.
Here is a good reverence:
https://pythongeeks.org/switch-in-python/

Comment: Hi Poder, thanks for the reply. However, as the RDO day of each staff is not absolutely fixed (of course it will be definitely better if it can be constantly same). It needs to be determined by solver as well. So I guess switch case also not the best option in this case, do you agree?

Comment: I think I don't exactly understand what you want to do then. You need to have different operations depending on the RDO. For example people how don´t work on Monday need to do the M shift on Wednesday or something like this. Do these requirement change and what detriments these requirements?

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation.

Comment: The situation is that every worker will required to have 6 working days and 1 day off per week. For the RDO (day off) day, it will be great for having a fixed schedule for workers (Say worker A can have every Monday off). However, it is not a must condition (For example, if next Monday requires more workforce than usual, then we have to move some of the workers' day off from Monday to rest of the week in order to have sufficient supply). So, I would say a fixed RDO is preferable but can be violated if necessary.